# Checking if at least 1 tuple is in another list of tuples in python

Tags: tuples

I'm trying to build a function to check 2 lists of tuples, and return True if at least one of the tuples is in the other list:

```
def g32(x, y):

    for i in range(len(x)):
        for j in range(len(y)):
            if x[i] in y[j]:
                return True
    return False

g32( [(3,5),(2,8)] , [(6,5),(3,5),(7,2)])
False
```

Expected True since (3,5) is in both lists, ideas? Thanks

p.s would like to use simple syntax like this since it's for school and some built in python functions can't be used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the `in` operator in a tuple, it will return the elements of this. In your case you will be comparing: `if (3, 5) in 3:` and `if (3, 5) in 5:`, in each case returns `False`.

Must be use:

```
def g32(x, y):
    for i in range(len(x)):
        if x[i] in y:
            return True
    return False

print(g32( [(3,5),(2,8)] , [(6,5),(3,5),(7,2)]))
```

Output:

```
True
```

**Suggestion:**

```
def g32(x, y):
    for X in x:
        if X in y:
            return True
    return False
```

If there is a change of order:

```
def g32(x, y):
    for X in x:
        if X in y:
            return True
        if (X[1], X[0]) in y:
            return True

    return False

print(g32( [(3,5),(2,7),(4,4),(8,3)] , [(6,5),(3,3),(7,2)] ))
```

Output:

```
True
```

Comment: Would the first work if the y list is bigger then the x one? Also i forgot to mention that there could be some who's order are switched like this one: [(3,5),(2,7),(4,4),(8,3)] , [(6,5),(3,3),(7,2)] in which (2,7) and (7,2) should evaluate True

Comment: @stasisOo The answer to the first question: yes.

Comment: @stasisOo 
If my answer will help you mark it as correct please.

Comment: Give me a sec to test it out and i will if it works!